# Highcharts - Change line style in line gaps (null)

Tags: highcharts

I have a series with **many** null values all over the place on the line. I need the gap between those values to be represented with a dotted-line or whatever (another color).

Any help will be very welcome :)
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before starting, let me confess that its an interesting problem but very much solvable using Highcharts. Though this will need a bit of work.

This is how I would implement this:

**Algo:**
For every series S, create an another auxiliary series S'. S' job is to fill the gaps. S' can be a dotted line of same color. For every gap, consecutive nulls, in S, let say gap starts at point L(x1,y1) and ends at point R(x2,y2). Points L and R needs to be there on S'. Lets say points L and R are m units away from each other where m>=2. We need to insert m-1 points between L and R. We can do this by linear interpolation. We will call these points as P1, P2 .. Pm-1 where Pi = { x2-x1 + i, y1 + (y2 -y1)/m }

**Usability:**
If lets say you have series T, Q, R ans S in your original chart. After application of above algorithm, you will have 4 more series named T', Q', R' ans S'. In legend, 8 series will be visible. But we want only 4 - the original ones. You can accomplish this by using 'linkedTo' property of series. So T' will be linked to T, S' will be linked to S and so on. As a result, legend of S' will not be shown and when you toggle S by clicking legend, S' will automatically toggle.

linkedTo : http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.linkedTo

**Location of code:**
As mentioned in algo, you need to read existing series and insert auxiliary series. You can do this in the load() callback function which is called when the chart has finished loading and all the series are available to access.
Load Callback : http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.load
Adding a series : http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.addSeries()

Cheers!

Comment: yes, that's what I thought... just a lot of gymnastic I was hoping not to make.I believe null value display management should be something included in Highscharts don't you think!?

Comment: Yeah, I think it would be a great feature request. It seems this feature request has already been made by someone:
http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1010275-add-broken-line-segments-for-null-values

Comment: I just ran into this comment and it saved my day. Here a [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkyRhO/7aqhx8ac/)